# Используется или употребляется?

Tags: лексика

Эти слова, согласно словарю, являются **синонимами**, и их удобно включать в текст,чтобы избежать повторения.

Но меня заинтересовал тот факт, что формы глаголов  ***используется*** и ***употребляется*** имеют **частотность в Нацкорпусе 4000/1400.**

**С чем это связано?** Может быть, семантика глаголов все-таки имеет заметные отличия?

Comment: С разной сочетаемостью. Напр. в том же корпусе обратная статистика для сочетаний "использовать выражение" / "употребить выражение" - 4:12.

Comment: Мне кажется, что разница здесь в следующем. Использовать выражение: использовать то, что есть в языке. Употребить выражение: употребить для выражения конкретной мысли, сделать выбор в пользу этого выражения.

Comment: Да, наверное, употребление ближе к потребителю и конкретнее. Чтобы _использовать_ что-либо в пищу, нужно _применить_ кулинарные навыки и тогда уже _употребить_ результат их применения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Это частичный ответ, с ссылкой на источник.)

Я рекомендую посмотреть "Новый объяснительный словарь синонимов русского языка" Апресяна Ю.Д. Там синонимичному ряду "*использовать, пользоваться, употреблять, применять, эксплуатировать, утилизировать*" посвящено 6 страниц убористого текста в две колонки. Сложно выделить коротко основные отличия; ниже я попытаюсь законспектировать часть этой словарной статьи, акцентировав внимание только на различиях употребления этих двух слов.

1. **Использовать** можно человека или другое живое существо.
2. **Употребляют**
   обычно достаточно простые бытовые инструменты (**использовать** можно
   сложные приборы и механизмы).
3. **Использовать** допускает бОльшую свободу
   в придании объекту непредусмотренных функций.
4. Имеется зависимость от
   стационарности объектов (можно **использовать** особенности рельефа, но не **употреблять** их).
5. По
   характеру цели **использовать** может предполагать более отдалённые
   цели, а **употреблять** — скорее ближайшую, непосредственную цель.

> **Использовать** и **пользоваться** — два самых употребительных слова ряда,
>   причём первое обладает наименьшей семантической спецификой, а второе —
>   наименьшей стилистической и жанровой спецификой.

Глагол **употреблять** в XIX веке было относительно точным синонимом **использовать**.
В современном языке **употреблять** сохраняется главным образом в сочетании с названиями таких объектов, которыми легко манипулировать и которые расходуются в процессе использования.

> Однако наиболее свободно этот синоним [**употреблять** — grizzly] используется в современном языке в сочетании с названиями элементов языковой или другой подобной информации.

Comment: Да, спасибо, вроде бы понятно, глаголы соответствуют мотивирующим существительным. Использовать (извлечь пользу для решения своей проблемы) - это общее понятие, а употребляют что-то в соответствии с возникшей необходимостью (трѣба - нужда), поэтому здесь более частный характер "пользы".